# Install from USB failed

Tags: system-installation, usb, wubi

I made an install USB stick to instructions in another computer and when I tried to use it in the one I wanted Ubuntu, it failed to boot - yes, I changed the boot sequence. I ran the exe that introduces Ubuntu and it gave the option to install alongside Windows [XP], so I chose that. It seemed to be getting along nicely, but then broke off to Dos with the following message:

```
[   6.324451]ACPI PCC probe failed
BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)

(initramfs) _
```

I have no idea what it all means, and can't understand the tech talk so was counting on an 'idiot's install' doing it all for me. What do I do?